# Redirect not working for SAML login, php-saml with Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml, onelogin

I've integrated SAML using php-saml to connect using WSO2 Server Identity Server for local and it's working perfectly.

However, the redirection is not working in case of Azure Active Directory. It just redirects to [office.com](https://www.office.com/?auth=1) and stays there.

Here's the SAML Response for Azure:

```html
ResponseData
status      302
statusText  
httpVersion http/2.0
redirectURL https://login.microsoftonline.com/
headersSize -1
bodySize    -1
_transferSize   690
_error  null
```

SAML Response for WSO2 :

```html
Response Data
status  302
statusText  Found
httpVersion HTTP/1.1
redirectURL http://app.test
headersSize 884
bodySize    0
_transferSize   884
_error  null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please make sure Redirect URI present in the code  ex: https://your.domain.name/oauth.php must be given in redirect url app registrations in azure portal and then please check if configuration for SAML with entity url, signle sign on url etc.. are correct.
2. Make sure to update IDP and sp in metadata to upload during saml configuration.
3. Azure ad only supports Https protocol, make sure your redirect url starts with Https except for localhost
   Go through the below document step by step for further details

**Reference:**
[Azure AD Single Sign-On with SimpleSAMLphp – My IT Daily (wordpress.com)](https://nathansenblog.wordpress.com/2021/02/23/azure-ad-single-sign-on-with-simplesamlphp/)

Comment: For me, it worked by changing the configuration in 'sp' array. Changed 'NameIDFormat' to 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified' from 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent'