# Negative SAML authentication response

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, okta

I have an application that I need to do the authentication to an IDP (Azure) and if the authentication fails I want that the IDP to send back a response to my application that user is not authorise .the issue is that IDPs are not sending any information regarding the authentication failed and is just remaining on login screen.
Any ideas?
Best regards,
Mircea

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the SSO protocol used, Azure AD will always return an [error code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-aadsts-error-codes), message and debugging information.

If that's not the case, then [Collect a network trace with Fiddler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-web-pubsub/howto-troubleshoot-network-trace#collect-a-network-trace-with-fiddler) and post the results here minus any confidential information for additional debugging.

Optionally, you may try to [Test SAML-based single sign-on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/debug-saml-sso-issues) from the Azure Portal to verify your application correct configuration.

Comment: Thank you!the authentication is working fine if the user exists in Azure but external users that have no Azure accounts are stuck at login page.I want to redirect back to my application in that case.Is this possible?i found this for SameSite https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/symantec-security-software/identity-security/siteminder/12-52-01/configuring/partnership-federation/saml-2-0-feature-configuration/configure-a-saml-2-0-response-for-authentication-failure.html#concept.dita_95a8883c2f5dd6e9ed6f84fb8ce70578b07a5fb0_DefineaResponsewiththeNegativeAuthenticationResponseAttribute

Comment: Hello, what is displayed when the users get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is an issue with the Redirect URI being used in the application for the event when user is not found on the IDP (Azure AD). This seems to quite similar to the following issue: [Redirect not working for SAML login, php-saml with Azure Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71235067/redirect-not-working-for-saml-login-php-saml-with-azure-active-directory)